# PHPs call_user_func_array in Python

Tags: php, python

Is there an equivalent in Python for PHP's [call_user_func_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your function name is a string, you could do:

```
getattr(obj, 'func')(*arr)     # where obj is the namespace that hold func
```

Answer (score 11):

Call the function with the array preceded by *:

```
function(*array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your can call function and pass arguments by `*` sign
ex.

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

arg = (1, 2)
add(*arg)
```

You also can use dict to pass argument pairs by double star `**`

ex.

```
arg = {a: 1, b: 2}
add(**arg)
```